# Loaded HTML Text In Flash not displaying with BlendMode.LAYER

Tags: html, flash, text

Have a textField in which I'm loading HTML formated text into it. This textField sits inside a parent container which has its blendMode property set to BlendMode.LAYER. When I run the movie, the html text doesn't display. Any clues why?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you set the blendMode to normal, does the text display?  Are you sure it's a blendMode issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
textField.embedFont = true;
textField.defaultformat = new Format("EmbedFontName");
```

Do you have something like this?

or embed font characters?

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work with normal blend mode either:

- Does the loaded html contain unsupported html tags? Flash text fields support only a limited subset of [html tags](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText).
- If not, it could be embedded fonts issue as konrad suggested.